# AFNetworking setUploadProgressBlock not behaving goes straight to 100%

Tags: ios, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue, uiprogressview, afnetworking

I am using the AFNetworking Framework to facilitate photo uploads to a website.  The uploads work fine, but I need to show progress in a UIProgressView.  Problem is, the progress moves from 0 to 100% a second or so after the upload starts and sits at 100% for some time depending on the number of photos being uploaded.  I am uploading between 1 and 6 photos at a time using a single request.  Any ideas on what's going on here?  Is AFNetworking not including the size of the photos?
It shows properly in NSLOG:

```
2012-04-03 10:49:45.498 PhotoUp[3689:2207] Sent 32768 of 217931 bytes
2012-04-03 10:49:45.499 PhotoUp[3689:2207] Sent 65536 of 217931 bytes
2012-04-03 10:49:45.501 PhotoUp[3689:2207] Sent 98304 of 217931 bytes
2012-04-03 10:49:45.502 PhotoUp[3689:2207] Sent 131072 of 217931 bytes
2012-04-03 10:49:47.795 PhotoUp[3689:2207] Sent 134310 of 217931 bytes
2012-04-03 10:49:49.070 PhotoUp[3689:2207] Sent 136730 of 217931 bytes
2012-04-03 10:49:50.819 PhotoUp[3689:2207] Sent 139150 of 217931 bytes
2012-04-03 10:49:52.284 PhotoUp[3689:2207] Sent 141570 of 217931 bytes
```

Here's the code:

```
NSString *numberOfPhotosAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", numberOfPhotos];


NSString *fileBase = @"file0_";
NSString *fileNameBase = @"SourceName_";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mywebsite.com"];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        numberOfPhotosAsString, @"PackageFileCount",
                        wtID, @"wtID",
                        @"PU", @"type",
                        nil];
for (int i= 0; i < numberOfPhotos; i++)
{
    [params setObject:[fileNames objectAtIndex:i] forKey:[fileNameBase stringByAppendingFormat:@"%i", i]];
}

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/ReceivePhoto.aspx" parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) { 

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPhotos; i++)
{
    // may want to experiment with the compression quality (0.5 currently)
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([images objectAtIndex:i], 0.5);
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:[fileBase stringByAppendingFormat:@"%i", i] fileName:[fileNames objectAtIndex:i] mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
}
}];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesWritten, NSInteger totalBytesWritten, NSInteger totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
    NSLog(@"Sent %d of %d bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
    float progress = totalBytesWritten / totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
    [selectLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", progress]];
    [progressView setProgress: progress]; 
    //[testProgressView setProgress:progress];
}];
[operation  setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    [self imageRequestDidFinish];


} 
                                  failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                      NSLog(@"error: %@",  operation.responseString);

                                  }
 ];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line does an integer division:

```
float progress = totalBytesWritten / totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
```

You need to cast at least one operand to float:

```
float progress = totalBytesWritten / (float)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
```

Comment: I tried to post that answer, but didn't have enough rep to answer own question within 8 hours.  You are correct though, what a rookie mistake!  Thanks!